# submit POST request to Salesforce through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, salesforce, tls1.2

My code used to work before but it stopped working since Salesforce updated from TLS 1.0 encryption protocol to TLS 1.2.

Can you please let me know what modifications i should make in order to my code to work or send information to Salesforce with TLS 1.0 disabled and TLS 1.2 enabled.

This is my code below:

```
public static string WRequest(string URL, string method, string postData)
{
  string responseData = "";
  HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
  request.Accept = "*/*";
  request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
  request.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1";
  request.Timeout = 60000;
  request.Method = method;
  if (request.Method == "POST")
  {
   request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
   UTF8Encoding encodingutf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
   byte[] postByteArray = encodingutf8.GetBytes(postData);
   request.ContentLength = postByteArray.Length;
   Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream();
   postStream.Write(postByteArray, 0, postByteArray.Length);
   postStream.Close();
  }
  HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
  if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
   Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
   responseData = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
  response.Close();
  return responseData;
}
```

Comment: You should debug your code first. Nobody will be able to help you without debug information. What is being sent to the server? What is the server returning?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this line to your code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

It worked for me.